# Parallax images not sizing properly in mobile view

Tags: html, image, parallax, image-size

I am working on a website and I used the style element to add a parallax image to each of my pages and I can't figure out why the images are zoomed in way too much in the mobile view. The images all look fine when I preview them on my laptop, even the mobile view, but when I view them on my phone, the images are zoomed in too much. The website is https://emrsmith.github.io/sammies/. This is what I have now in my HTML:

```
<style> 
    .parallax {
      background-image: url("images/IMG_2504.JPG");
      min-height: 812px; 
      background-attachment: fixed; 
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover; 
    }
</style>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would appreciate the help.
*The problem only occurs when used on a mobile phone.*